# Joining two MySQL datasets by date as well as id

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am struggling to find a way to efficently join two datasets using a single query

Dataset one can be returned using the following query:

```
SELECT hours_person_id, hours_date, hours_job, SUM(hours_value) AS hours
FROM hours
WHERE hours_status = 1
GROUP BY hours_person_id, hours_date, hours_job
```

which gives a dataset similar to

```
| 1 | 2020-06-07 | 101 | 25 |
| 1 | 2020-06-07 | 102 | 10 | 
| 1 | 2020-06-07 | 103 |  5 |
| 2 | 2020-06-07 | 101 | 30 |
| 2 | 2020-06-07 | 104 | 10 |
```

From which we can get total hours per week, per job, etc...

Our second dataset gives us the hourly rates for the each person. The problem is that this table contains both *historical* and *future* hourly rates, so the join needs to ensure that the rate applies to the correct **person_id** and **date**. There could also be more than 1 rate for a person on a date.

The following gives all the rates that are active

```
SELECT rate_person_id, rate_date, rate_value
FROM rates
WHERE rate_active = 1
```

Which could look like

```
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 20.00 |
| 1 | 2020-05-01 | 25.00 | 
| 1 | 2020-07-01 | 22.00 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 22.00 | 
| 2 | 2020-05-01 | 24.00 | 
| 3 | 2020-05-01 | 20.00 |
| 3 | 2020-05-01 | 21.00 |
| 3 | 2020-07-01 | 18.00 |
```

So for the **hours** above the rate from the `2020-05-01` would be the expected result, with the `21.00` value being the result for `person_id === 3`

Can what I am looking for be done in a single Query, or am I better off Joining two subqueries?

**Update**
As requested here is a fiddle that represents the above
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oiUpTnajY6M6ZTfZgRf4kT/0
As you can see we have a query that returns the correct data, but this query does not scale to our curennt data set (1.8m lines and more sub tables)

Comment: You will definitely need to Structure your Query Language with subqueries or common table expressions to make this work. You can do it in a single structured query.

Comment: If there is no job_id in rates dataset then subquery seem to be the only solution.

Comment: *So for the hours above the rate from the 2020-05-01 would be the expected result, with the 21.00 value being the result for person_id === 1* ??? rate_value=21.00 matches rate_person_id=3, not 1... Maybe not 21.00 but 25.00?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Hadn't found `sqlfiddle` before will see what I can do... the actual data set we are dealing is much larger so I'm abstracting the bits that aere important.
@Akina good catch - it should have been person_id = 3

Answer (score 0):

> So for the hours above the rate from the 2020-05-01 would be the expected result, with the 21.00 value being the result for person_id === 1

From your rates output, person_id = 1 was never on rate value 21.00 .

```
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 20.00 |
| 1 | 2020-05-01 | 25.00 | 
| 1 | 2020-07-01 | 22.00 |
```

For 2 active rates for a person, do you need the most recent rate or you need the rate in the month where he worked. If there is no rate for that month then do you want 0 rate or something else.

Comment: As pointed out in a comment it was person_id = 3 that had the dual dates

Comment: What rates is expected for person_id = 1  ? and reason ?

Comment: Expected rate would be `25.00` because the `hours_date` is < `2020-07-01` but > `2020-05-01`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT h.*,
       (SELECT rate_value
        FROM rates r
        WHERE h.hours_person_id = r.rate_person_id AND
              r.date <= h.date
        ORDER BY r.date DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) as rate_value
FROM hours h
```

I don't see what `active` has to do with the question, because you need to go back in time.  You can then aggregate or do whatever you want once you have the correct rate on the date.

Comment: `active` potentially comes into play with the "future" rates. and with `active = 0` should be ignored. However they are not strictly relevant to the exact problem

Comment: @DanKelly . . . I don't even see how that is an issue for this query, assuming that "active" means that the rate is currently active.  The dates should identify what rates are correct at a given time -- and it should be the rate on or before any given date.

Comment: That's true. We can ignore the active for the given example. there are other use cases where we are potentially looking at future hours when active is important. not here

Comment: @DanKelly . . . Even for the future, if you have other rates going into effect, I assume you want want to calculate using those.  The `active` flag seems useful for many queries, but not this one.

Comment: Looking at your example on the fiddle it appears that it is returning the values the earliest date i.e. `| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 20.00 |`. I'm assuming that syntax would need any SUM etc in an outer query?

Comment: @DanKelly . . . I'm surprised it even worked.  The `order by` was referring to the outer table.  Fixed.